# How can to test in Espresso without R.id.edit_text?

Tags: java, android-espresso

I create dynamic fields in my class. And I cannot to write EditTexts in layout (.xml), so I have not `R.id.edit_text`, How Can to test edit text without R.id.edit_text in Espresso 2? If I have R.id.edit_text - I can write `onView(withId(R.id.edit_text)).perform(typeText("123"));` But I have not the `R.id.edit_text`.

Comment: Examine with hierarchy viewer and locate your view with a combination of matchers. See example: http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/05/espresso-match-toolbar-title.html. If you need more help, post a screenshot from hierarchy viewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`withId` is only one of view matchers. You could you use others that are suitable for you case. You could check under `ViewMatchers` of `com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.matcher`.
Google code could be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/espresso/lib/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.java).

Also [hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) matchers could help to have more complex conditions.

One of samples could be this:

```
onView(allOf(
    isAssignableFrom("class name"), 
    withText("Text to match")))
    .perform(...);
```

You could also write your own matcher if you need more complex one.
I am recommending also to read [the Espresso documentation](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/).